# how to split train-test data on stacked features?

Tags: python, knn, training-data

I have a dataset in CSV format, from which I have taken few column labels as features and I have stacked them using stack() function. Next, I need to split train-test data and apply K-NN function on new sub-dataset consisting of stacked features. I need the code for the same.

I have already used row selection loc function of stacked features and assigned values x1 & y1, for 15000 points, for further performing train-test split but still, I am getting an error.

```
from scipy.sparse import hstack
S1 = hstack((categories_one_hot, sub_categories_one_hot,text_bow1,text_bow, price_standardized))
x1 = S1.iloc[:,:-1].values[:15000]
y1 = S1.iloc[:,:5].values
```

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
>        in ()
>       ----> 1 x1 = S1.iloc[:,:-1].values[:15000]
>             2 y1 = S1.iloc[:,:5].values
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py in **getattr**(self, attr)
>           686             return self.getnnz()
>           687         else:
>       --> 688             raise AttributeError(attr + " not found")
>           689 
>           690     def transpose(self, axes=None, copy=False):
>
> AttributeError: iloc not found

Comment: `iloc` is for pandas data frames

Comment: i think sparse matrix is used for numpy array, i have x as 20k rows and y as 5 columns so, 5 features or dimensions so can you share the code for ho to use numpy array to get 20k rows and 5 columns